# How to remove cell spacing in Kendo Angular grid?

Tags: angular, cell, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid, cellspacing

I'm trying to use one column of a grid as a canvas for grouping lines using borders. I want the borders between two rows to touch to give the effect of a continuous line.
How do I remove cell spacing on the grid?

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your demo.